# Has anyone got the Android NDK toolchains to run on ARM instead of x86 or x86_64?

Tags: android, compiler, toolchain

I have been going over the "dev scripts" in the `$NDK/build/tools` directory of the Android NDK and have been modifying them to build host/build tool-chains that run on ARM instead of x86 or x86_64. For instance:

```
edge-case@Flubber:/opt/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt
/linux-x86/bin$ file arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386,
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for
GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```

I want it to be for ARM not Intel 80386 or any Intel derivative, unless its an Intel ARM (I think there are/was Strongarm? can't recall atm ;p).

If not, I guess I can do it myself. Almost to the point where I think I can compile the gcc tools for arm without the scripts stopping me first. I can't really cross compile anything on my old a$$ HP right now, it only has 512MB of ram and my phone has 4x that with a dual core processor where as my HP is but one core and 10+ years old. I'm basically SOL after a borked Windows install on a partition of my Laptop (Just to play Neverwinter), which had 8 gigs of ram and a 2.6 ghz dual core 64 bit cpu, screwed up my BIOS, not sure what MS was doing with their dirty fingers all over my BIOS, but what ever, I never want to see a start menu for the rest of my life. I've borked at least 20 *nix based installs and never was my computer left inoperable, atm I can't even get into my BIOS to change anything, just a black screen no matter what I do.

Anyways, I have tried Google'ing stuff like "Android NDK for arm" or "Android NDK run on arm" but can't find anything. The Ubuntu repos have the arm-linux-androideabi-* tools, but likewise, for x86 and x86_64 only. I don't need a cross compiler to compile native stuff, I need a native compiler to compile native stuff, hope that makes sense.

Has this already been accomplished? It would save me some time, say if I could look over their build scripts and maybe incorporate them into the r9d revisions.

Comment: I have the same issue, i want to install Android NDK in arch linux chroot (with linux deploy) on my Android device, but i still not downloaded the source code yet (over 5GB!)
My device has 64GB so storage is not a problem but my internet connection is slow and i have to keep device 7/24 open for weeks (i guess a successful compile will take a week with two 1Ghz ARM cores)
For instructions you can visit:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/README.md#Building-the-NDK
Also there is a third party application that include arm build of ndk:
https://github.com/android-ide/aide_ndk

Comment: Is it possible to use the ndk provided by the aide project to compile the Linux kernel

Comment: if it's about programming then it should be on https://stackoverflow.com/, otherwise it should be on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nsikak If you use TermuxArch and install gcc you may be able to.